# Invalid Windows version when using Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, windowsversion

A user is having problems installing my software. This is his OS:

[image: OS]

This is his system:

[image: System]

He gets this error when installing:

[image: Error]

In my [`Code]` section I have the following:

```
function MakeVersion(Major, Minor, Build: Cardinal): Cardinal;
begin
    Result := (Major shl 24) + (Minor shl 16) + Build;
end;

{ Called just before setup is about to start }
function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var
    WindowsVersion: Cardinal;
begin
    Result := True;

    { Check Windows Version }
    WindowsVersion := GetWindowsVersion;
    Log(Format('Windows Version: %x', [WindowsVersion]));
    (* Windows must be Win 7 SP1 (6.1.7601), Win 8.1 (6.3.9200) or higher, eg: Win 10 (10.0.10240)
        See: http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=winvernotes
        Microsoft .Net Framework 4.6.2 will only work with these operating systems. *)
    if (WindowsVersion <  MakeVersion(6, 1, 7601)) or
         ((WindowsVersion >= MakeVersion(6, 2, 0)) and (WindowsVersion < MakeVersion(6, 3, 0))) then
    begin
        MsgBox(SetupMessage(msgWindowsVersionNotSupported), mbError, MB_OK);
        Result := False;
    end;
end;
```

I think I am going to have to ask him again because in the log this is what it says:

> 2020-06-21 15:07:18.055   Windows version: **6.2.9200**  (NT platform: Yes)

According to [here](https://www.lifewire.com/windows-version-numbers-2625171) it says:

> Windows 8 6.2.9200

I will re-confirm with him.

Here is the log:

```
2020-06-21 15:07:18.055   Log opened. (Time zone: UTC-05:00)
2020-06-21 15:07:18.055   Setup version: Inno Setup version 6.0.5 (u)
2020-06-21 15:07:18.055   Original Setup EXE: C:\Users\pltrc\AppData\Roaming\Meeting Schedule Assistant\AutoUpdate\MeetSchedAssistSetup.exe
2020-06-21 15:07:18.055   Setup command line: /SL5="$D0CE8,11801715,780800,C:\Users\pltrc\AppData\Roaming\Meeting Schedule Assistant\AutoUpdate\MeetSchedAssistSetup.exe" /SPAWNWND=$C0CB6 /NOTIFYWND=$240D86 
2020-06-21 15:07:18.055   Compatibility mode: Yes (Win8RTM Installer)
2020-06-21 15:07:18.055   Windows version: 6.2.9200  (NT platform: Yes)
2020-06-21 15:07:18.055   64-bit Windows: Yes
2020-06-21 15:07:18.055   Processor architecture: x64
2020-06-21 15:07:18.055   User privileges: Administrative
2020-06-21 15:07:18.110   Administrative install mode: Yes
2020-06-21 15:07:18.110   Install mode root key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
2020-06-21 15:07:18.110   64-bit install mode: No
2020-06-21 15:07:20.131   Created temporary directory: C:\Users\pltrc\AppData\Local\Temp\is-MEE3F.tmp
2020-06-21 15:07:20.140   -- DLL function import --
2020-06-21 15:07:20.140   Function name: idpAddFile
2020-06-21 15:07:20.140   DLL name: files:idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.140   Extracting temporary file: C:\Users\pltrc\AppData\Local\Temp\is-MEE3F.tmp\idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.148   Dest DLL name: C:\Users\pltrc\AppData\Local\Temp\is-MEE3F.tmp\idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.148   Importing the DLL function.
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   Successfully imported the DLL function. Delay loaded? No
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   -- DLL function import --
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   Function name: idpAddFileComp
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   DLL name: files:idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   Dest DLL name: C:\Users\pltrc\AppData\Local\Temp\is-MEE3F.tmp\idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   Importing the DLL function.
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   Successfully imported the DLL function. Delay loaded? No
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   -- DLL function import --
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   Function name: idpAddMirror
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   DLL name: files:idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   Dest DLL name: C:\Users\pltrc\AppData\Local\Temp\is-MEE3F.tmp\idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   Importing the DLL function.
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   Successfully imported the DLL function. Delay loaded? No
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   -- DLL function import --
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   Function name: idpAddFtpDir
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   DLL name: files:idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   Dest DLL name: C:\Users\pltrc\AppData\Local\Temp\is-MEE3F.tmp\idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   Importing the DLL function.
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   Successfully imported the DLL function. Delay loaded? No
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   -- DLL function import --
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   Function name: idpAddFtpDirComp
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   DLL name: files:idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   Dest DLL name: C:\Users\pltrc\AppData\Local\Temp\is-MEE3F.tmp\idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   Importing the DLL function.
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   Successfully imported the DLL function. Delay loaded? No
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   -- DLL function import --
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   Function name: idpClearFiles
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   DLL name: files:idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   Dest DLL name: C:\Users\pltrc\AppData\Local\Temp\is-MEE3F.tmp\idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   Importing the DLL function.
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   Successfully imported the DLL function. Delay loaded? No
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   -- DLL function import --
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   Function name: idpFilesCount
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   DLL name: files:idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   Dest DLL name: C:\Users\pltrc\AppData\Local\Temp\is-MEE3F.tmp\idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   Importing the DLL function.
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   Successfully imported the DLL function. Delay loaded? No
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   -- DLL function import --
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   Function name: idpFtpDirsCount
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   DLL name: files:idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   Dest DLL name: C:\Users\pltrc\AppData\Local\Temp\is-MEE3F.tmp\idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   Importing the DLL function.
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   Successfully imported the DLL function. Delay loaded? No
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   -- DLL function import --
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   Function name: idpFileDownloaded
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   DLL name: files:idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   Dest DLL name: C:\Users\pltrc\AppData\Local\Temp\is-MEE3F.tmp\idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   Importing the DLL function.
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   Successfully imported the DLL function. Delay loaded? No
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   -- DLL function import --
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   Function name: idpFilesDownloaded
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   DLL name: files:idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   Dest DLL name: C:\Users\pltrc\AppData\Local\Temp\is-MEE3F.tmp\idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   Importing the DLL function.
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   Successfully imported the DLL function. Delay loaded? No
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   -- DLL function import --
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   Function name: idpDownloadFile
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   DLL name: files:idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   Dest DLL name: C:\Users\pltrc\AppData\Local\Temp\is-MEE3F.tmp\idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   Importing the DLL function.
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   Successfully imported the DLL function. Delay loaded? No
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   -- DLL function import --
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   Function name: idpDownloadFiles
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   DLL name: files:idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   Dest DLL name: C:\Users\pltrc\AppData\Local\Temp\is-MEE3F.tmp\idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   Importing the DLL function.
2020-06-21 15:07:20.181   Successfully imported the DLL function. Delay loaded? No
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   -- DLL function import --
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Function name: idpDownloadFilesComp
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   DLL name: files:idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Dest DLL name: C:\Users\pltrc\AppData\Local\Temp\is-MEE3F.tmp\idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Importing the DLL function.
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Successfully imported the DLL function. Delay loaded? No
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   -- DLL function import --
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Function name: idpDownloadFilesCompUi
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   DLL name: files:idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Dest DLL name: C:\Users\pltrc\AppData\Local\Temp\is-MEE3F.tmp\idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Importing the DLL function.
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Successfully imported the DLL function. Delay loaded? No
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   -- DLL function import --
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Function name: idpStartDownload
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   DLL name: files:idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Dest DLL name: C:\Users\pltrc\AppData\Local\Temp\is-MEE3F.tmp\idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Importing the DLL function.
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Successfully imported the DLL function. Delay loaded? No
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   -- DLL function import --
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Function name: idpStopDownload
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   DLL name: files:idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Dest DLL name: C:\Users\pltrc\AppData\Local\Temp\is-MEE3F.tmp\idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Importing the DLL function.
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Successfully imported the DLL function. Delay loaded? No
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   -- DLL function import --
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Function name: idpSetLogin
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   DLL name: files:idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Dest DLL name: C:\Users\pltrc\AppData\Local\Temp\is-MEE3F.tmp\idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Importing the DLL function.
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Successfully imported the DLL function. Delay loaded? No
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   -- DLL function import --
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Function name: idpSetProxyMode
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   DLL name: files:idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Dest DLL name: C:\Users\pltrc\AppData\Local\Temp\is-MEE3F.tmp\idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Importing the DLL function.
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Successfully imported the DLL function. Delay loaded? No
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   -- DLL function import --
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Function name: idpSetProxyName
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   DLL name: files:idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Dest DLL name: C:\Users\pltrc\AppData\Local\Temp\is-MEE3F.tmp\idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Importing the DLL function.
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Successfully imported the DLL function. Delay loaded? No
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   -- DLL function import --
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Function name: idpSetProxyLogin
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   DLL name: files:idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Dest DLL name: C:\Users\pltrc\AppData\Local\Temp\is-MEE3F.tmp\idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Importing the DLL function.
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Successfully imported the DLL function. Delay loaded? No
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   -- DLL function import --
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Function name: idpConnectControl
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   DLL name: files:idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Dest DLL name: C:\Users\pltrc\AppData\Local\Temp\is-MEE3F.tmp\idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Importing the DLL function.
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Successfully imported the DLL function. Delay loaded? No
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   -- DLL function import --
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Function name: idpAddMessage
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   DLL name: files:idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Dest DLL name: C:\Users\pltrc\AppData\Local\Temp\is-MEE3F.tmp\idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Importing the DLL function.
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Successfully imported the DLL function. Delay loaded? No
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   -- DLL function import --
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Function name: idpSetInternalOption
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   DLL name: files:idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Dest DLL name: C:\Users\pltrc\AppData\Local\Temp\is-MEE3F.tmp\idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Importing the DLL function.
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Successfully imported the DLL function. Delay loaded? No
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   -- DLL function import --
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Function name: idpSetDetailedMode
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   DLL name: files:idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Dest DLL name: C:\Users\pltrc\AppData\Local\Temp\is-MEE3F.tmp\idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Importing the DLL function.
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Successfully imported the DLL function. Delay loaded? No
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   -- DLL function import --
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Function name: idpSetComponents
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   DLL name: files:idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Dest DLL name: C:\Users\pltrc\AppData\Local\Temp\is-MEE3F.tmp\idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Importing the DLL function.
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Successfully imported the DLL function. Delay loaded? No
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   -- DLL function import --
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Function name: idpReportError
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   DLL name: files:idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Dest DLL name: C:\Users\pltrc\AppData\Local\Temp\is-MEE3F.tmp\idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Importing the DLL function.
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Successfully imported the DLL function. Delay loaded? No
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   -- DLL function import --
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Function name: idpTrace
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   DLL name: files:idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Dest DLL name: C:\Users\pltrc\AppData\Local\Temp\is-MEE3F.tmp\idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Importing the DLL function.
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Successfully imported the DLL function. Delay loaded? No
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   -- DLL function import --
2020-06-21 15:07:20.182   Function name: idpAddFileSize
2020-06-21 15:07:20.183   DLL name: files:idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.183   Dest DLL name: C:\Users\pltrc\AppData\Local\Temp\is-MEE3F.tmp\idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.183   Importing the DLL function.
2020-06-21 15:07:20.183   Successfully imported the DLL function. Delay loaded? No
2020-06-21 15:07:20.183   -- DLL function import --
2020-06-21 15:07:20.183   Function name: idpAddFileSize
2020-06-21 15:07:20.183   DLL name: files:idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.183   Dest DLL name: C:\Users\pltrc\AppData\Local\Temp\is-MEE3F.tmp\idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.183   Importing the DLL function.
2020-06-21 15:07:20.183   Successfully imported the DLL function. Delay loaded? No
2020-06-21 15:07:20.183   -- DLL function import --
2020-06-21 15:07:20.183   Function name: idpGetFileSize
2020-06-21 15:07:20.183   DLL name: files:idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.183   Dest DLL name: C:\Users\pltrc\AppData\Local\Temp\is-MEE3F.tmp\idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.183   Importing the DLL function.
2020-06-21 15:07:20.183   Successfully imported the DLL function. Delay loaded? No
2020-06-21 15:07:20.183   -- DLL function import --
2020-06-21 15:07:20.183   Function name: idpGetFilesSize
2020-06-21 15:07:20.183   DLL name: files:idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.183   Dest DLL name: C:\Users\pltrc\AppData\Local\Temp\is-MEE3F.tmp\idp.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.183   Importing the DLL function.
2020-06-21 15:07:20.183   Successfully imported the DLL function. Delay loaded? No
2020-06-21 15:07:20.183   -- DLL function import --
2020-06-21 15:07:20.183   Function name: LoadVCLStyleW
2020-06-21 15:07:20.183   DLL name: setup:files:VclStylesInno.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.183   Extracting temporary file: C:\Users\pltrc\AppData\Local\Temp\is-MEE3F.tmp\VclStylesInno.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.248   Dest DLL name: C:\Users\pltrc\AppData\Local\Temp\is-MEE3F.tmp\VclStylesInno.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.248   Importing the DLL function.
2020-06-21 15:07:20.626   Successfully imported the DLL function. Delay loaded? No
2020-06-21 15:07:20.626   -- DLL function import --
2020-06-21 15:07:20.626   Function name: LoadVCLStyleW
2020-06-21 15:07:20.626   DLL name: uninstall:{%TEMP}\VclStylesInno.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.626   Skipping.
2020-06-21 15:07:20.626   -- DLL function import --
2020-06-21 15:07:20.626   Function name: UnLoadVCLStyles
2020-06-21 15:07:20.626   DLL name: setup:files:VclStylesInno.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.627   Dest DLL name: C:\Users\pltrc\AppData\Local\Temp\is-MEE3F.tmp\VclStylesInno.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.627   Importing the DLL function.
2020-06-21 15:07:20.627   Successfully imported the DLL function. Delay loaded? No
2020-06-21 15:07:20.627   -- DLL function import --
2020-06-21 15:07:20.627   Function name: UnLoadVCLStyles
2020-06-21 15:07:20.627   DLL name: uninstall:{%TEMP}\VclStylesInno.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.627   Skipping.
2020-06-21 15:07:20.627   -- DLL function import --
2020-06-21 15:07:20.627   Function name: ShowWindow
2020-06-21 15:07:20.627   DLL name: user32.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.627   Dest DLL name: user32.dll
2020-06-21 15:07:20.627   Importing the DLL function.
2020-06-21 15:07:20.627   Successfully imported the DLL function. Delay loaded? No
2020-06-21 15:07:20.627   Extracting temporary file: C:\Users\pltrc\AppData\Local\Temp\is-MEE3F.tmp\Amakrits.vsf
2020-06-21 15:07:20.949   Windows Version: 60223F0
2020-06-21 15:07:20.949   Message box (OK):
                          This program does not support the version of Windows your computer is running.
2020-06-21 15:07:25.760   User chose OK.
2020-06-21 15:07:25.760   InitializeSetup returned False; aborting.
2020-06-21 15:07:25.760   Got EAbort exception.
2020-06-21 15:07:25.760   Deinitializing Setup.
2020-06-21 15:07:25.911   Log closed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your user seems to be running the installer in Windows 8 compatibility mode:

> Compatibility mode: Yes (Win8RTM Installer)

Comment: I did not notice this entry in the log! Now I see it. :) I am bringing it to the attention of the user. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you run any official Inno Setup example on that target system and get log from it?

So far there were no issues in Inno Setup Windows detection algorithm so we need to find out where is a catch.